# Hosting my own files on Google CDN

Tags: google-app-engine, cdn, blobstore

I want to improve performance of my site by hosting the images via a CDN. A lot of my visitors are in locations that have a poor connection so I want to minimize the latency. The Google Blobstore appeals to me because it can also resize the images.

Does the google blobstore work like a CDN, whereby the files are served by a server that's close to you?

For instance this cropped image: https://lh3.ggpht.com/vNEsJryv2f0D1uqmusa8EdTDd5-CIiqz8AkTscCb6o5E493aM1pPxS3Zm_iX1c1UuZw2oR2lx6GwKUoUk0FYB6uG5A=s131-c

If it's not, what's a good alternative?

Answer (score 2):

All requests served by Appengine go [through Google CDN](http://davepeck.org/2011/10/25/a-word-on-app-engine-caching/).

All you need to do it set appropriate `Cache-Control` response headers on any response and it will get cached by Google CDN. You can also set [caching on static files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Setting_the_Cache_Expiration).

**Update:**

As far as I can see you serve images via AppEngine Image service, which under the hood uses Google High Performance Image Service. Requests to your images do not hit your front-end instances, they are directly served by image service servers, so you only pay for bandwidth. Also, this responses have a cache time of 1 day, so they even get cached by downstream caches, even lowering your cost and speeding things up.

Comment: But Lukas uses the Google High Performance Image Service. His images are served using a get_serving_url by Google, see his url. Google will take care of it. He does not serve his own images. He does not use a handler. It will only cost him bandwith. And it is very very fast. So why worry about the location of the files, from a technical perspective.

Comment: Google Image Service already cached the images as long you invoke getServingURL(). The URL will be deleted only if you call deleteServingURL().

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google App Engine servers are only located in North America, and some part in Europe. Refer to [Google Group Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/67mZ3bXIqWk).

So if you are located in other continent, your request are still routed to North America.

Currently Windows Azure has the capability to choose the region of your server. [image]. From my experience there is even Singapore and some countries in Middle East.

Comment: Please share your reason on the vote down. Is it because of the Azure?  Note that the question stated 'if there is alternative'. Or is it because of the App Engine Server only located in America + Europe? Note that we are not talking about Google server here, but Google App Engine Server.